# How can I make nginx support @font-face formats and allow access-control-allow-origin?

Tags: nginx, http-headers

I've added these rules to `mime.types`:

```
application/x-font-ttf                ttf;
font/opentype                         otf;
application/vnd.ms-fontobject         eot;
font/x-woff                           woff;
```

Now the Content-Type header is being set properly per each of those. My only issue now is that Firefox requires Access-Control-Allow-Origin. I have googled this [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/162429/how-do-i-add-access-control-allow-origin-in-nginx) and added this to my server directive:

```
location ~* \.(eot|ttf|woff)$ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}
```

but now my fonts aren't being served at all.

Instead the `error.log` reports that it's trying to open them on the local filesystem..

> 2010/10/02 22:20:21 [error] 1641#0:
>   *15 open() "/usr/local/nginx/html/fonts/mgopenmodernabold-webfont.woff"
>   failed (2: No such file or directory),
>   client: 69.164.216.142, se    rver:
>   static.arounds.org, request: "HEAD
>   /fonts/mgopenmodernabold-webfont.woff
>   HTTP/1.1", host: "static.arounds.org"

Any ideas what could be off with the syntax? Do I need to explicitly add a rule saying don't try to open it locally or what?

**EDIT**: I think the problem is that I'm serving 2 different locations now. And instead of that I should do the regex check inside of the main one then feed the header.

Comment: You also can add "otf" in your rule

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Woot! Got it.. It was pretty much what I suspected in my edit, I had to basically do the regex filename check in my sole `location {}` instead of making an alternative one.

```
    location / { 
            root /www/site.org/public/;
            index index.html;

            if ($request_filename ~* ^.*?/([^/]*?)$)
            {
                set $filename $1; 
            }

            if ($filename ~* ^.*?\.(eot)|(ttf)|(woff)$){
                add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
            }
    }
```

Comment: No. You really don't. You just need to learn about context inheritance. If you specify the site root directive in your server block then it'll be available in all location blocks. I suggest you read this: http://blog.martinfjordvald.com/2010/07/nginx-primer/

Comment: Someone actually mentioned that to me in the #nginx channel but I forgot to update the answer.

Answer (score 13):

```
location ~* \.(eot|ttf|woff)$ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}
```

If you have other font extensions, pay close attention to add them as well. Nowdays it common to have: eot|ttf|woff|woff2|svg, so you should adjust like so:

```
location ~* \.(eot|ttf|woff|woff2|svg)$ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}
```

Comment: **NOTE:** If the given solution doesn't work for you, read [this](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs/issues/85) and [this](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs/blob/master/nginx/conf/cross-domain-fonts.conf). It's enlightening, and you may find the reason it isn't working.

Comment: This does not work for me as the font url contain query string

Comment: works for me...

Comment: *Hint :* if you cloudflare purge them !!

Answer (score 7):

## All assets

This will make all assets work fine. 
You can add `root` if you want to define a new location

```
location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|html|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|eot|otf)$ {
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*";
    expires 1M;
    access_log off;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

Comment: Yep this broke everything

Answer (score 5):

another solution : put all your fonts in, for example, `static/fonts`, and add

```
location /static/fonts  {
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" *;
    alias /var/www/mysite/static/fonts;
}
```