# CORS in Nginx 1.2.1 (Debian 7)

Tags: nginx, cors

I am using Debian 7 and Nginx 1.2.1. Http headers module is enabled by default with Debian packets (https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx).
I am trying to add links to facebook, twitter and google plus accounts using their given links (with images hosted on their side). Problem is that my browser does not display these 3 images. I were using Apache before and had the module and instruction `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` in my site config.

I moved to Nginx and cannot manage to get the equivalent working with the following configuration. I also have Naxsi enabled, using a set of generic rules for wordpress.

No error logs, no idea where to inspect to find the beginning of an answer. All that I found on the internet are these similar questions with similar answers, unfortunately for me (e.g. [How do I add Access-Control-Allow-Origin in NGINX?](https://serverfault.com/questions/162429/how-do-i-add-access-control-allow-origin-in-nginx)).

```
server {
 listen 192.0.2.3:80; 
 server_name blog.example.com;

 root /blog/example;
 index index.php;

 location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args; 

   add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
}
location ~ \.php$ {
  try_files $uri =404;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  include fastcgi_params;
}

if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|POST|HEAD)$ ) {
  return 444;
}

# location ~* \.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff)$ {
#   add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
# }
}
```

Also, `curl -I blog.example.com` displays (missing the header directive for cross-origin ?)

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 28 May 2015 06:59:26 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.39-0+deb7u2
X-Pingback: http://blog.example.com/abc
```

I need to recompile Nginx in order to add some other modules and was wondering if headers more could help (https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module), though http headers module should be enough apparently.

Thanks for your support.

EDIT 1:

Just realised I was completely wrong and actually did not get it. It is about loading fonts from another domain. In my browser console, I can see I am loading the fonts from another domain (that are not displayed in my browser). No error, I get http code 200, and yet 0KB downloaded (so nothing to be displayed) and when I open the file in a new tab, I can download the content (so it is actually available).

Comment: You are using an ancient version of nginx. `I am trying to add links to facebook, twitter and google plus accounts using their given links (with images hosted on their side)` This has nothing to do with Access-Control-Allow-Origin on your site, please _demonstrate_ a problem - it doesn't look like what you think it is (and also sounds off topic). Also, fwiw, putting things in the / location block will have no effect if it's not the location block handling the request (which is the case, since it's handled by the php location block).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
I tried adding `add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';` everywhere I could but it didn't help (although your comment is quite true !).
I do not have access to the website files, I am just required to set nginx so that "it works" : the last person that had setup this had apache and the same problem occurred, which was solved, _apparently_ , by using `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` in apache sites-available conf. The equivalent in nginx appears to be what I am trying to set up but does not change anything.

Comment: Please re-read my first comment =) **please _demonstrate_ a problem**. The absence of the header is not a problem, the js/whatever error related to `my browser does not display these 3 image` is the problem - what images, and what error? check your browser console.

Comment: I realised some stuff and edited my original post. It probably changes a bit what I was first describing... hopefully makes it clearer !